# Claims management in wso2 is troubleshoot

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am experiencing a problem with wso2 identity server (version 4.5.0) regarding some new claims (attributes) i have added. Specifically, i have added new attributes in http://wso2.org/claims but when i try to populate the corresponding fields to the user profiles, the following message appears:

> Error while updating user profile of User. Error is: One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported by underlying LDAP.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be due that,  you have add a claim mapping which is not supported by under line user store (LDAP). When you are adding a claim,  we need to provide claim mapping attribute.  It is the map attribute with your LDAP user store. If there is no such attribute in the LDAP user store, this error can be occur. (Please note claim management component would not add new attribute to user store. It would map with the existing attributes in the LDAP user store)

Comment: You are right Asela! I replaced the nulls in Mapped Attributes with existing ones which are supported and the problem was solved! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Maria, Asela - Could you please guide, how we can provide claim mapping attribute in LDAP user store? Could you please provide more details / steps etc? I'm facing issues.  Thanks, Neha

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to piggyback off of Aslea and Maria answer and add onto them. If you'd like to know what mapped claims you can use, you can find about them in this [link](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200001/msg00079.html). And if you'd like to add custom attributes directly to the LDAP server, please refer to this [link](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com.eg/2011/02/how-to-introduce-custom-attributes-to.html).